# Is there a standard governing the __utma, __utmz etc.. cookies?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

Whether I log into Facebook or Twitter, I'll be bombarded with cookies of the such names as:

```
__utma
__utmb
__utmc
__utmv
```

What are their functions ? 
Is there a standard that governs how these are used on the serverside ?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [Webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These are cookies generally associated with [**Google Analytics**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_analytics).

See this [info](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html#HowGAUsesCookies) from Google itself.
BTW, the ***UTM*** prefix originally stood for ***Urchin Tracking Module***, whereby Urchin Software Corp is a company acquired by Google in 2005 and which product was used as the basis for Google's initial offering in the Web Site Analytics market.

Comment: Old post but +1 for explaining UTM.

Answer (score 2):

These are cookies that come from Google Analytics. I couldn't immediately find the reference in Facebook's page source, but Twitter has it, and I've seen it plenty of times before in my own websites that use Google Analytics.

[Here is an overview of the cookies](http://code.google.com/intl/nb-NO/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html) Analytics uses.