# Showing correct cookies in a fancybox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies, fancybox

H_i

I want to see page with a fancybox (http://fancybox.net/)
The cookie.php file is simple:

```
<?php
   var_dump($_COOKIES);
?>
```

If i get it without fancybox, it shows normally:

```
(array(3) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "54daefa8cae5929wq0f6bwa71257a74e" 
["mail"]=> string(4) "m@m.com" 
["hash"]=> string(40) "f59bdedb4b7aad275225e45106f34e137af29cdd" } 1)
```

If i want to see in a fancybox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
        'href' : 'http://example.com/cookie.php',
        'type' : 'iframe',
    });
});
```

Then it shows different cookies

```
'csrftoken' => string 'Vu3255XznLwCe4DVnsMsxprPVId4VAUI' (length=32)   
'__utma' => string '111872281.1095020375.1459185662.1349185660.1359285660.1' (length=55)
'__utmz' => string '111871281.1339155660.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)' (length=70)   
'PHPSESSID' => string 'd56u3fi3l3lo7qlli1iv2m58g7' (length=26)
```

Can anybody give advice what to do?

Regards: fb beginner

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823406/what-does-utma-mean

Answer (score 0):

The fancybox shows an usual iframe, and borwser doesn't isolate session in the iframe.
Some old versions of browsers, like Opera and IE, isolate session in the iframe, but modern browsers don't do so.
You need to check path at the address bar and in the href-option fancybox and check whether your site distinguishes requests with www. and without www. />In general, if it shows different cookies-array keys in the first case and in the second case, it says: they are different pages: the first page hasn't Google Analytics code, but the second page has this: `__utma` and `__utmz`.
If checking of the paths will not give result, then I need more information.